# User unable to see a scheduled post via the url?

Tags: scheduled-posts

My users aren't able to see scheduled posts. Instead they get shown a `404` error. I'd like to show scheduled posts as well.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question, this way it's poor standard - see: [Help: How to Ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Like I mentioned on your other question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117240/how-to-move-the-published-posts-to-trash you are maybe not getting the concept of scheduled posts - they will be visible after the scheduling time, because then they will be published.

Comment: I suspect that you are trying to use scheduled posts for something they are not meant for. Please explain the actual problem/project that you are working on.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to display the scheduled posts in the main wordpress loop you can use `'post_status' => 'future'` as an argument for the array. This will now show your scheduled posts for all users. It's pretty handy for things like event listings.

However there is a problem with this and I believe this is what your problem may be. When any user with a role set lower than editor, or a non-user, tries to access that post on it's individual page you will not have the rights to view it, and it throws up a 404.

Not sure why this is and why admins and editors can see it.

If you place this code in your `functions.php` file it should get it working for everyone.

```
    /* Show future posts */
function show_future_posts($posts)
{
   global $wp_query, $wpdb;
   if(is_single() && $wp_query->post_count == 0)
   {
      $posts = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request);
   }
   return $posts;
}
add_filter('the_posts', 'show_future_posts');
```

I found it from this post on Wordpress

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-future-post-on-single-pageview